# SQL Complex update query filter distinct values only

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update, inner-join

I have 3 tables with following columns.

1. Table: A with column: newColumnTyp1, typ2
2. Table: B with column: typ2, tableC_id_fk
3. Table: C with column: id, typ1

I wanted to update values in A.newColumnTyp1 from C.typ1 by following logic:

1. if A.typ2=B.typ2 and B.tableC_id_fk=C.id
2. the values must be distinct, if any of the conditions above gives multiple results then should be ignored. For example A.typ2=B.typ2 may give multiple result in that case it should be ignored.

edit:

2. the values must be distinct, if any of the conditions above gives multiple results then take only one value and ignore rest. For example A.typ2=B.typ2 may give multiple result in that case just take any one value and ignore rest because all the results from A.typ2=B.typ2 will have same B.tableC_id_fk.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.typ1, B.typ2
FROM C
  LEFT JOIN B ON C.id = B.tableC_id_fk
  LEFT JOIN A ON B.typ2= A.typ2
```

it gives me a result of table with two columns typ1,typ2
My logic was, I will then filter this new table and compare the type2 value with A.typ2 and update A.newColumnTyp1
I thought of something like this but was a failure:

```
update A set newColumnTyp1= (
SELECT C.typ1 from
SELECT DISTINCT C.typ1, B.typ2
FROM C
  LEFT JOIN B ON C.id = B.tableC_id_fk
  LEFT JOIN A ON B.typ2= A.type2 
where A.typ2=B.typ2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking of an updateable CTE and window functions:

```
with cte as (
    select a.newColumnTyp1, c.typ1, count(*) over(partition by a.typ2) cnt
    from a
    inner join b on b.type2 = a.typ2
    inner join c on c.id = b.tableC_id_fk
)
update cte
set newColumnTyp1 = typ1
where cnt > 1
```

---

Update: if the columns have the same name, then alias one of them:

```
with cte as (
    select a.typ1, c.typ1 typ1c, count(*) over(partition by a.typ2) cnt
    from a
    inner join b on b.type2 = a.typ2
    inner join c on c.id = b.tableC_id_fk
)
update cte
set typ1 = typ1c
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: @StackDummy: ok. See my pdate

Comment: Thanks again, i tried with :   with cte as (
    select a.newColumnTyp1 as atyp1, c.typ1 as ctyp1, count(*) over(partition by a.typ2) cnt
    from a
    inner join b on b.type2 = a.typ2
    inner join c on c.id = b.tableC_id_fk
)
update cte
set atyp1= btyp1
where cnt > 1

Answer (score 1):

I think I would approach this as:

```
update a
    set newColumnTyp1 = bc.min_typ1
    from (select b.typ2, min(c.typ1) as min_typ1, max(c.typ1) as max_typ1
          from b join
               c
               on b.tableC_id_fk = c.id
          group by b.type2
         ) bc
     where bc.typ2 = a.typ2 and
           bc.min_typ1 = bc.max_typ1;
```

The subquery determines whether `typ1` is always the same.  If so, it is used for updating.

I should note that you *might* want the most common value assigned, instead of requiring unanimity.  If that is what you want, then you can ask another question.